# Uninstall app returns "not successful" error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

From my app, I am properly firing an intent to uninstall an application. However, once the user accepts the uninstall dialog prompt, the app is not uninstalled and a text error is shown:

> "Uninstall not successful"

I added following permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UNINSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

How to completely uninstall it?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't add those permissions - you cannot acquire them as a third party application developer.  The only way you can uninstall applications is via the Intent, and user confirmation, which does not require permissions.  Can the application in question be uninstalled from the settings menu?  Perhaps it is a system app or one forced on the user by the carrier, and not able to be uninstalled by normal means.

Comment: I am handling it via intent but as you say, it is a system app. So, no way to uninstall it?

Comment: Not without changing the security model of the device ("rooting", custom rom, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void uninstall(String pack)
{
    Uri packageuri = Uri.parse("package:" + pack);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageuri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and delete permissions to uninstall etc.

For example: uninstall("com.android.chrome"); - uninstall google chrome. This isn't work with system app.